# Issue with changing img resource android

Tags: java, android

I am having this problem when I try to change the source/resource of a image(a button) when is pressed and released.

```
        Btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            /*if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ImageBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn1);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                ImageBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn0);
            }*/

            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ImageBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn1);
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    ImageBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn1);
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the code, I tried what is in the comment too, but no result. I do have to mention that the button changes its resource just when touching it, but after releasing it, it doesn't change.

The button listener is on a relative layout(also defined as a relative layout in the xml code), in java however is defined as a button.

Comment: "the button changes its resource just when touching it, but after releasing it, it doesn't change" - your ACTION_UP code only re-sets the same resource set by your ACTION_DOWN code, so it doesn't seem like you should expect to see any change.  If you want it to show something different on release, you will have to supply a different resource as your argument there.

Comment: Oh... shame on me. I've been on this problem for 15 mins and didn't notice that. Anyways, thank you for your answer. Now it works :D.

Comment: Not a problem. Often I make small mistakes like that too and spend hours trying to figure out what it could be :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of the button doesn't change from when you touch it to when you release it because you are setting the same background resource.

Both cases contain:

`ImageBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn1);`

Set one of them to a different image.